# Distributed tensorflow allocations

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-computing, deep-learning

I have two related questions on controlling the distributed training for an experiment with 2 machines each having multiple GPUs.

1. Following the tensorflow [Distributed Inception guidelines](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception#how-to-train-from-scratch-in-a-distributed-setting), I see that each process implements the data preprocessing queues and readers; now to achieve data parallelism with either synchronous or asynchronous replicated training, how does TF make sure that each worker processes a minibatch that no other worker has or will process for a particular epoch? Since all queue-runners point to the same dataset, is there some built-in coordination between workers to not process the same examples more than once in one epoch (e.g. in sync SGD)?
2. Is it possible to specify the GPU device for each worker process as well; as part of the cluster spec? Or does it need to be mentioned in code while running the training op or something? Or is this not recommended?